# Kendo DropdownList MVC bind JS function on Read Success

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo ASP.NET MVC and have a `Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor` control with `DataSource`. The DataSource is binded in cshtml file. I need to capture the success event of read in jquery. In Kendo Jquery we can have something as follows.

```
        read: {
            url: "/Test/GetById",                
            success: function(result) {
                //custom code;
            }
        }
```

How can I have the same thing in MVC control.

```
            Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Prop)
            .DataTextField("Field")
            .DataValueField("Id")
            .DataSource(dataSource =>
            {
            dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("Action", "CTRL"));
            });
```

Is there any event that I should capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [requestEnd](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/events/requestend) and the [error](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/events/error) events can be used for this. If for some reason your read method fails, the error event will be triggered. Otherwise, the requestEnd event will be triggered. You can then check for `type` in the event data to be equal to `read`, meaning the Read method successfully finsihed.

Here is an example:

```
<script>
    function onError(e) {
        console.log(e.status) // displays "error";
    },

    function onRequestEnd(e) {
        if (e.type === "read") {
            // Read method successfully finished
        }
    }
</script>

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
  .Name("products")
  .DataTextField("ProductName")
  .DataValueField("ProductID")
  .DataSource(source => 
  {
      source.Read(read => read.Action("RemoteDataSource_GetProducts", "DropDownList"));
      source.Events(events => events.Error("onError").RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"));
  })
)
```

Take a look at the configuration page for [kendo.data.DataSource](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) to get more info on events.